# MOODLE-PHP Error Log

Tags: php, moodle

Could anyone help me with these errors?
I am getting them from the `code checker` plugin.,

```
if·($this->content·!==·null){

Expected "if (...) {\n"; found "if (...){\n"

#38: ········if(isloggedin()·and·!has_capability('moodle/site:config',·get_context_instance(CONTEXT_SYSTEM)))·{

Expected "if (...) {\n"; found "if(...) {\n"

#44: ············if($courseid·>·1)·{

Expected "if (...) {\n"; found "if(...) {\n"

#49: ················foreach($criteriamods·as·$ctmds)·{

Expected "foreach (...) {\n"; found "foreach(...) {\n"
```

Comment: Is that really a PHP error log? Looks more like codesniffer results reporting incorrect spacing around the parentheses. (incorrect in terms of standard Moodle coding style)

Comment: To confirm - this looks like the output from https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=local_codechecker which checks the Moodle Coding style found here http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Coding_style

Comment: Yes Davosmith, it was error reporting from code checker plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: these are not PHP errors.
Bad news: they are violations of standard Moodle coding style.

Which means that fixing these "errors" will not have any effect on the way the code runs, but should (hopefully) lead to code which is easier for most Moodle developers to read and understand.

In all of the "errors" you have listed, the complaint looks to be related to spacing around the parentheses. For example, in the first one you need to put some space between the closing parenthesis ) and the opening brace {.

It's a similar story for the others. Once you have identified the appropriate lines of code, make sure there are spaces before the opening parentheses and after the closing parentheses.

Comment: Thank You Chris Throup, you are right, all the errors are with spacing